# How does timed JSON web signature serializer work?

Tags: flask, access-token, secret-key

Can I restrict actions of my API to specific users if I generate a token like this:

```
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer

expiration = 600
s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in = expiration)
return s.dumps({ 'id': kwargs.get('user_id') })
```

And the verification

```
@staticmethod
    def verify_auth_token(token):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token)
        except SignatureExpired:
            return None # valid token, but expired
        except BadSignature:
            return None # invalid token
        user = User.query.get(data['id'])
        return user
```

I don't understand how this works and achieves security. The way I'm used to securing an API for example, a user wants to do **HTTP PUT** to /posts/10 I'd usually get the post's author ie **user_id** then query the database get the token for that user_id, if the request token matches the queried token then it is safe for the **PUT**. I've read this [article](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask) and don't fully understand how it achieves security without storing anything in a database. Could someone explain how it works?

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/

Answer (score 6):

By signing and sending the original token upon login the server basically gives the front end an all access ticket to the data the user would have access to, and the front end uses that token (golden ticket) on all future requests for as long as the token is not expired (tokens can be made to have expiration or not). The server in turn knows the token has not been tampered with, because the signature is basically the encrypted hash of the users recognizable data (user_id, username, etc). So, if you change the token information from something like:

```
{"user_id": 1}
```

to something like:

```
{"user_id": 2}
```

then the signature would be different and the server immediately knows this token is invalid.

This provides an authentication method that exempts the server from having to have a session, because it validates the token every time.

[Here](https://jwt.io/) is an example of what a token **could** look like (itsdangerous can use this format of JSON web tokens)

Comment: I know is an old post, but it could help someone else in the future :)